# How to simplify conditional instructions block to one elif statement in python app?

Tags: python, cmd, lan

I wrote simple app that allows to ping machines in local network of my school's computer lab and reboot/turn them all off, or one by one. App works well, but it contains large block of elif statements assigned to specified machines in the lab (there are 18 computers):

```
def shutdown_all():
    with open(os.devnull, "wb"):
        for computer in range(1, 19):
            ip = "pracownia{0}".format(computer)
            subprocess.call('shutdown -s -t 0 /m \\\\%s' % ip)
    print("\nTask complete\n")


def shutdown_selected(ip):
    with open(os.devnull, "wb"):
        machine = "pracownia{0}".format(ip)
        subprocess.call('shutdown -s -t 0 /m \\\\%s' % machine)
    print("\nTask complete\n")


while True:
    mode = input()
    if mode == 'exit':
        break
    elif mode == "shutdown -all":
        shutdown_all()
    elif mode == "shutdown -ip 1":
        shutdown_selected(1)
    elif mode == "shutdown -ip 2":
        shutdown_selected(2)
    elif mode == "shutdown -ip 3":
        shutdown_selected(3) 

        ...

    else:
        print("Wrong mode. Type valid command.")
```

Is it possible to simplify the instruction and reduce the entire block to one elif statement allowing the user to input which computer he wants to ping/reboot/shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as previous answer but using a regex to parse as the IPs can be 1-2 digits.

```
import re
mode = input()
if mode == 'exit'
    break
elif mode == 'shutdown -all'
    shutdown_all()
elif mode[:12] == 'shutdown -ip':
    match = re.search(r'\d+', mode)
    if match:
        ip = match.group()
        shutdown_selected(ip)
```

Comment: Works well too, like a previous answer, but without the bug with "-<random two signs>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A common way to reduce complexity of large if-else trees is to use dictionaries. However, you will offload the comeplexity to somewhere else. For example this:

```
options = dict(foo = foo, bar = bar, foobar = foobar)
options.get(input("Enter an option"), print('Input is not an option'))
```

This example shows that you have three different functions for three different option  keywords. The method **get** will look for the option in the dictionary else it will print and error message.

With regard to your code I would offload the complexity to one function as such:

```
def shutdown(command):
    computers = set(str(i) for i in range(1,19))

    with open(os.devnull, "wb"):
        selecComputers = set(command.split(' ')[2:]) # or use regex
        if len(selectComputers) > 0:
           computers = computers.intersection(selectComputers)
        for computer in computers:
            ip = "pracownia{0}".format(computer)
            subprocess.call('shutdown -s -t 0 /m \\\\%s' % ip)
    print("\nTask complete\n")

while True:
    mode = input()
    if mode == 'exit':
        break
    elif 'shutdown' in mode:
        shutdown(mode)
    else:
        print("Wrong mode. Type valid command.")
```

Comment: The only issue is that solution won't work with more complex apps becouse I can type "shutdown -ip 13" and "shutdown -er 13" and it works the same way, but for needs of my program it works perfectly (**comment for people browsing for similiar solution**)

Comment: That's true I have no check after -ip. It is hard to tell what other options you can argeparse but editing the logic in that function is pretty straightforward to suite your needs combined with my comment above about dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do something like:

```
mode = input()
if mode == 'exit'
    break
elif mode == 'shutdown -all'
    shutdown_all()
elif mode[:12] == 'shutdown -ip':
    shutdown_selected(int(mode[-1:]))
```

You can add a bit to that last elif statement to make sure they are typing something that will work for your function - is that what you needed?

Comment: Not exactly. I am trying to achieve something similiar in work to windows command line, allowing user to type inside the app commands like "shutdown -ip 13", where "13" is the number of computer station named 'pracownia13'. I did that within that elif block, but I know it can be simplified.

Comment: I tried that with parsing, but it didn't fulfils the task - maybe I did not implement that properly